# Обращение к родителю из router outlet

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular-routing

Собственно вопрос в заголовке,можно ли как-то из router-outlet обратится к родителю.

У меня хедер в родителе,а остальное все в роутере. И мне надо при определённом действии обратится к родителю чтобы хедер обновился.

Код типа

```
<header>
<router-outlet>
<footer>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста добавляйте больше информации и описывайте подробнее задачу и сам вопрос, а также показывайте скрипт-код, что уже пытались делать.

Answer (score -1):

Dозможно стоит обратить внимание на именнованные router-outlet. Реализация есть насколько я знаю что в 1 что во 2м ангулярах